# доступ к store вне компонента

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Описываю класс в отдельном модуле. Хочу работать в нем с vuex. Внутри любого компонента я бы использовал: this.$store... и т.д. А как получить доступ к экземпляру store здесь? Передавать через конструктор, при создании экземпляра класса? Как то неэстетично, мне кажется...

Comment: `import store from '@/store/index.js'` как вариант

Comment: А как потом Вы планируете использовать этот класс? В отрыве от Vue?

Comment: @Дмытрык В классе есть статический метод getInstance. Ссылка на созданный объект хранится в коллекции в сторе, что дает возможность из прочих мест обращаться к нему. Наверное пложу костыльные велосипеды, только недавно пришел в веб из десктопа. Но пока очень не хватает привычных объектных подходов.

Comment: @MoloF  я предполагал, что при импорте `export default new Vuex.Store(`, каждый раз будет создаваться новый экземпляр со своими данными, но вроде все работает.

Comment: Если вы нашли решение своей проблемы, опубликуйте  ответ и пометьте галкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import store from '@/store/index.js'
```

позволяет полноценно работать в методах класса с vuex.